# Outputting correct Json from MVC controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, extjs

In my understanding, an Ext JS form panel wants the following input:

```
{
    'success': true,
    'data': {
        'name-field': 'Boogie',
        'number-field': '789789',
        'application-field': 'CE',
        'brand-field': 'GE', 
        'clientreport-field': '1',
        'moneyreport-field': '1',
        'billingreport-field': '1',
        'auditreport-field':'1'
    }
}";
```

But the following ASP.NET MVC controller:

```
public ActionResult FormLoader(string id)
{
    var result = repoS.GetClientSetting(id);

    return Json(new {success = true, data = result}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Returns the following output:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "Name": "Forngap",
            "Number": "lipo-900", 
            "Application": "EA",
            "Brand": "6.7.8",
            "ClientReport": false,
            "MoneyReport": false,
            "BillingReport": false,
            "AuditReport": false,
            "Login": "eeporp",
            "Password": "ungah",
            "Active": false
        }
    ]
}
```

With an extra set of "[ ]" around the "data" array. Can the controller above return what Ext JS forms want? Or does this require something besides Json? Thank you!

Comment: Seems to me, result is actually enumerable of some sort. Is it an array or a list or IEnumerable()? If so, add `using System.Linq;` to the file and use `result.First()`. If it really returns only one item, it would be better to change the type of result where it is defined/generated

Comment: Yes! Thank you, changing the return line to: return Json(new {success = true, data = result.FirstOrDefault()}, sonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); configured the Json correctly. Now I see the difference in LINQ between returning an array and a single item. Thank you again. If I had more reputation I'd +1 you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seams that:

```
var result = repoS.GetClientSetting(id);
```

returns array with 1 needed element, so try to pass only first element to `data`:

```
return Json(new {success = true, data = result [1]} ...
```

not sure is it correct syntax ( not working with ASP.NET )

or when loading data to form send first element of array data

```
....getValues( data[0] );
```

however fixing output would be better way

Comment: Yes, just like above, I now realize the LINQ used was returning an array rather than a single item, so translating your answer into C# works. Thank you!